# Swift sort an array of mixed object types according to date

Tags: arrays, swift

I have an of array objects each containing at least one date key of type `Date`

```
let arrayOfObjects: [Any] = [
    Cartoon(name: "Ben Ten", dateReleased: Date()),
    Milestone(dateReleased: Date()),
    Phone(color: "Black", dateReleased: Date())
]
```

I have such an array but with weigh more mixed object data types. All I want is to sort this array of objects in ascending order according to dateReleased for example in ascending order.

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define a `protocol` requiring a single `Date` object and make all your types that you want to sort conform to that protocol. Then you need to declare the array as `[Released]` and then simply call `sorted` on the it.

```
protocol Released {
    var dateReleased: Date { get }
}

struct Cartoon: Released {
    let name:String
    let dateReleased: Date
}

struct Milestone: Released {
    let dateReleased: Date
}

struct Phone: Released {
    let color:String
    let dateReleased: Date
}

let arrayOfObjects: [Released] = [
    Cartoon(name: "Ben Ten", dateReleased: Date()),
    Milestone(dateReleased: Date()),
    Phone(color: "Black", dateReleased: Date())
]

let sortedObjects = arrayOfObjects.sorted(by: {$0.dateReleased < $1.dateReleased})
```